# How to specify command-specific timeout per command in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I want all normal commands to have default timeout of 30 sec, but for one stored proc I need 5 min.

I don't want do this this unless it's the only way.

```
public partial class AContext : DbContext
{
    public AContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 300;
    }
}
```

How to attach timeout to this query only?

```
Context.Database.SqlQuery<AAAAA>("usp_AAAAA");
```

Comment: change it before executing the stored procedure and revert it after done :)

Answer (score 3):

You can set the [CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.commandtimeout(v=vs.113).aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.Database.CommandTimeout) on the [Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database(v=vs.113).aspx) property of the [DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx) directly, no need to try to get the object context from the [DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx).

Create a new [DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx) instance just for your execution and then get rid of it.

If you have a shared [DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx) instance you will have to wrap the call in a try/finally block and reset the timeout in the finally, this is so that the timeout will be reset even in the event of failure.

```
using(var Context = new AContext())
{
    Context.Database.CommandTimeout = 60*5; // 5 minutes
    var result = Context.Database.SqlQuery<AAAAA>("usp_AAAAA");
}
```

If the Context is shared.

```
try
{
    Context.Database.CommandTimeout = 60*5; // 5 minutes
    var result = Context.Database.SqlQuery<AAAAA>("usp_AAAAA");
}
finally{
    Context.Database.CommandTimeout = null; // reset
}
```